# jquery-1.8.1.min.js error on IE 8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Friends 
The following code throws an error on IE 8 and IE 9 as "Permission denied jquery-1.8.1.min.js"
However it works well on Chrome and Firefox 
what could be wrong

```
$(function() {

    var fileTypes = ['txt'];

    $('.input-file').find('input[type="file"]').live('change',function(e){
        $this = $(this)
        var ext = $this.val() === "" ? "" :this.value.match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
        if($this.val()){
             $this.parent().find('label').text($this[0].value)

        }
```

Please suggest

Comment: How are you including your JS file? Is it in your local or linked from a remote location?

Comment: Also, when is the error thrown?

Comment: why can't you do it this way? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811773/how-to-use-jquery-ui

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs in the code above?  Which line?

Comment: error occurs at $this.parent().find('label').text($this[0].value)

Comment: this code is a part of a js file

Comment: this error occus only in IE not in Chrome